# Bash array appending element issue

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have an array

```
declare -a her=("ger" "blr" "tyg" "")

for i in "${her[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

I get

```
ger
blr
tyg
```

But when I try and append to an array I  get one long string with no spaces

```
declare -a you

#without quotes and with quotes
#' " same result

for i in {"fgt","fe","ger"}; do
    you+=${i}
done

for i in "${you[@]}"; do
    $i
done

Fgtfeger
```

Any insight on whats happening ? Kinda makes them not as useful

Comment: Would be `you+=("${i}")`.

Comment: Use `declare -p you` for additional clues.

Comment: thanks for the tips. these arrays are newer to me at least in bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use Array Compound Assignment Syntax; Otherwise Use Length as Index

You have to append to an array using either the [compound assignment syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) (e.g. `foo=("elem1" ...)` or an array index.

#### Array Compound Assignment Syntax

The form with parentheses allows you to insert one or more elements at a time, and is (arguably) easier to read. For example:

```
# start with a clean slate
unset you

for i in "fgt" "fe" "ger"; do
    you+=("$i")
done

printf "%s\n" "${you[@]}"
```

This yields the values you'd expect:

> ```
> fgt
> fe
> ger
> ```

#### Insert at Index *Length*

You can get similar results by assigning to an index. For example:

```
unset you
for i in "fgt" "fe" "ger"; do
    you[${#you[@]}]="$i"
done
printf "%s\n" "${you[@]}"
```

This second example works because Bash arrays are zero-indexed, so the *length* of the array is also the next available index that should be assigned when appending.